# How can I specify the boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm size globally

Tags: boost, streambuf

I know that we can specify the size of streambuf as below in some function

```
boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm(512);
```

but in class how can we do the same thing

```
class test{
      public:
          boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm;
      void func1(){
          //statement
      }
      void func2(){
          //statement
      }
};
```

So my question is if we are having `boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm;` declared in above class then how can we specify the size of bufferstrm so that it can be available to all the functions of the class.

I tried below code

```
class test{
      public:
          boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm(1024);  // specified the size
      void func1(){
          //statement
      }
      void func2(){
          //statement
      }
};
```

But its giving error as cant initialize at the declaration point.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use NSMI with the correct syntax in C++14 and up:

```
class test {
  public:
    boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm { 1024 };
```

In fact, this is nothing but a shorthand for a constructor initializer list item, [in c++03 style](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/540839e78263e92c):

```
class test {
  public:
    boost::asio::streambuf bufferstrm;

    test()
       : bufferstrm (1024) // base/member initializer list
    {}
```

### Subclass

You can also consider creating a derived type that adds the initialization.

#### UPDATE Subclass idea

It turns out not so simple to make a subclass actually work with API's consuming `streambuf` as all the API's perform type-deduction on the buffer argument. Type deduction doesn't consider the conversion-to-base, so it fails to recognizes  classes derived from `streambuf`. Also, you **need** those overloads as `streambuf` is the only buffer type that is taken by reference.

I can see two solutions:

1. provide a conversion to `basic_streambuf_ref<>`
2. hack it by specializing `basic_streambuf<myalloc>` for an artificial allocator type just to add the initialization semantics.

#### Conversion to `basic_streambuf_ref<>`

You'll have to call it explicitly, but that's perhaps not the worst:

```
struct mystreambuf : boost::asio::streambuf
{
    using base_type = boost::asio::streambuf;
    mystreambuf() : base_type{1024} {}

    auto ref()
    {
        return boost::asio::basic_streambuf_ref<std::allocator<char>>{
            *static_cast<base_type*>(this)};
    }
};
```

Used as:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
tcp::socket sock(boost::asio::system_executor{}, {{}, 7878});

mystreambuf msb;
read_until(sock, msb.ref(), "\r\n\r\n");
```

See it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/reefGjY84)

#### Hacked allocator

```
template <typename T>
struct myalloc : std::allocator<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct boost::asio::basic_streambuf<myalloc<T>>
    : boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<T>>
{
    basic_streambuf() : base_type(1024) {}

    using base_type = boost::asio::basic_streambuf<std::allocator<T>>;
    using base_type::base_type;
    using base_type::operator=;
};

using mystreambuf1024 = boost::asio::basic_streambuf<myalloc<char>>;
```

Which can then be used as

```
mystreambuf1024 msb;
read_until(sock, msb, "\r\n\r\n");
```

See it [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/boMroxsqd)

Comment: Thanks for the answer 
but i have forgot to mention that I am using g++ below c++11 so the same code will work ??

Comment: @azharuddinkhan The second example already worked if you use parenthesis. Updated the answer with [live demo in c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/540839e78263e92c)